# memory leak in tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat

Good morning, does anyone know how to solve this in `jsf applications` after a reload, stop, or undeploy?

```
The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed), but their
    classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus causing a memory
    leak (use a profiler to confirm):
    /aplicacaojsf
```

Comment: Just don't stop, reload or undeploy your production environment without restarting tomcat. This is a fairly known problem, easily googlable.

Answer (score 0):

During development it's perfectly valid to do hot-deploy many times - it will result in an PermGen space error eventually (at least before using JDK 1.8) and you'll have to restart. The message is just a warning to the fact which happens to all containers when re-deploying, that parts of the previous classes are still in memory and will stay there until the end of days.

In production environment, it is good to restart the container - but even there it's not feasible all the times, since that may mean downtime for other applications as well. That's why commercial application servers like Oracle WebLogic do have a sophisticated admin console for jobs like that.